# To build a script from Eclipse to run commands in cmd

Tags: eclipse, cmd

I am using a set of commands to build my project in a expanded mode to deploy it in weblogic so each time i need to go to cmd and change directory to my project directory and run the command 'client dev fullexpanded' .

I want to make a script to run these commands which i running through cmd in my eclipse so each time i dont have to open cmd and write these commands

Comment: If I were you I'd convert my build to Maven and use the cargo plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Add the script as an External Tool (Program type) and you'll be able to fire it off from the toolbar.
[image: coolbar button]

Comment: thanks for your suggestion I have run my cmd file by this way but i am doing two task in my the cmd file one to build the project in expanded mode and run the server.first one is fine but it ends there  not running the next command which i used to  start the server